# addEventListener('mousedown' ... not working in canvas js

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have problem.

this code work perfect:

```
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>
var myGamePiece;
var myUpBtn;
var myDownBtn;
var myLeftBtn;
var myRightBtn;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myUpBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 50, 10);    
    myDownBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 50, 70);    
    myLeftBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 20, 40);    
    myRightBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 80, 40);                
    myGameArea.start();
}


var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        **document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);**
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
            myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
        })
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = false;
```

...

but when I change: document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
on code:

```
**const gameBoard = document.querySelector('.game__board');**

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 600;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        **gameBoard.appendChild(this.canvas);**
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="startGame()">
 <div id="game__board" class="game__board">
 </div>
</body>
```

this code not working. Keys dont move red block. Why? Help me please!

Comment: Don't use `insertBefore`, it's outdated, use `body.prepend(el)` and `gameBoard.append(el)`

Comment: I guess you are getting an error in the console